# Objc runtime set ivar with value

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to dynamically create a class with data loaded from JSON. I have successfully created the class, but still stuck at how to add several constants with the values loaded from the JSON.

For example, the JSON below:

```
"Josh": {
    "age": 10
}
```

I want a class like

```
class Josh {
    int age = 10;
}
```

However, I can only achieve

```
class Josh {
    int age;
}
```

with the following code:

```
Class Josh = objc_allocateClassPair([NSObject class], "Josh", 0);
class_addIvar(Josh, "age", sizeof(int), rint(log2(sizeof(int))), @encode(int));
objc_registerClassPair(Josh);
// Below is the desired result
Josh j = [[Josh alloc] init];
NSLog([j age]); // prints 10
```

So can anybody answer me, how to add the primitive value 10 to this Ivar I've added? Thank you

Comment: So are you creating an object from that class? `Josh person = [[Josh alloc] init]; person.age = 10;`?

Comment: @AlejandroIván you'd need to set the ivar directly, since the runtime-created class won't have accessor methods like `-setAge:` yet, but the principle is sound.

Comment: @AlejandroIván what I'm thinking is `Josh person = [[Josh alloc] init]; NSLog(person.age);` this gives me 10 directly without me setting anything else

Comment: Hmm... maybe using associated objects? http://nshipster.com/associated-objects/

Comment: @AlejandroIván I was thinking about it, but it does not support syntax like `[person age]` nor `person.age` right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**What you are doing is almost certainly madness and you shouldn't be messing with it.**

That said, the code you wrote doesn't even compile.

So let's fix it.

You can't declare `Josh j`, because `Josh` is a variable, not a type. Instead you can use `id`, which means “any Objective-C object”.

```
id j = [[Josh alloc] init];
```

You also can't say `[j age]` unless you declare an `age` method somewhere, so stick this somewhere:

```
@protocol Dummy <NSObject>
- (int)age;
@end
```

You also can't say `NSLog([j age])` because `[j age]` returns an `int`, not an `NSString *`. So do this instead:

```
NSLog(@"%d", [j age]);
```

Now you'll find that you get an “unrecognized selector” error, because you didn't add an `age` method to your `Josh` class. To do that, you first have to import the Objective-C runtime:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>
```

Then you can add an `age` method like this:

```
        Ivar ageIvar = class_getInstanceVariable(Josh, "age");
        ptrdiff_t ageIvarOffset = ivar_getOffset(ageIvar);

        IMP ageImp = imp_implementationWithBlock(^int(id self) {
            void *base = (__bridge void *)self;
            return *(int *)((unsigned char *)base + ageIvarOffset);
        });
        class_addMethod(Josh, @selector(age), ageImp, "v@:");
```

Here's the complete, compilable, non-crashing program:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@protocol Dummy <NSObject>
- (int)age;
@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        Class Josh = objc_allocateClassPair([NSObject class], "Josh", 0);

        class_addIvar(Josh, "age", sizeof(int), rint(log2(sizeof(int))), @encode(int));

        Ivar ageIvar = class_getInstanceVariable(Josh, "age");
        ptrdiff_t ageIvarOffset = ivar_getOffset(ageIvar);

        IMP ageImp = imp_implementationWithBlock(^int(id self) {
            void *base = (__bridge void *)self;
            return *(int *)((unsigned char *)base + ageIvarOffset);
        });
        class_addMethod(Josh, @selector(age), ageImp, "v@:");

        objc_registerClassPair(Josh);
        // Below is the desired result
        id j = [[Josh alloc] init];
        NSLog(@"%d", [j age]); // prints 10
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But it still just prints “0“:

```
2018-06-25 15:07:53.179809-0500 madness[35050:5762222] 0
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

If you want to initialize `age` to 10, you need to override `init` in your `Josh` class. If you were writing the `init` method normally, it would look like this:

```
- (instancetype)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _age = 10;
    }
    return self;
}
```

But we can only send to `super` in something the compiler recognizes as a method body, and a block (like we'll pass to `imp_implementationWithBlock`) doesn't count as a method body. So we have to do the `[super init]` part the hard way, by calling `objc_msgSendSuper`. To do that, we have to import another header:

```
#import <objc/message.h>
```

Then we can write the block that implements `init`:

```
        IMP initImp = imp_implementationWithBlock(^id(id self) {
            struct objc_super superInfo = {
                .receiver = self,
                .super_class = NSObject.self
            };
            id (*msgSendSuper)(struct objc_super *, SEL) = (id (*)(struct objc_super *, SEL))objc_msgSendSuper;
            self = msgSendSuper(&superInfo, @selector(init));
            if (self) {
                void *base = (__bridge void *)self;
                *(int *)((unsigned char *)base + ageIvarOffset) = 10;
            }
            return self;
        });
        class_addMethod(Josh, @selector(init), initImp, "@@:");
```

Here's the complete program:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <objc/runtime.h>
#import <objc/message.h>

@protocol Dummy <NSObject>
- (int)age;
@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        Class Josh = objc_allocateClassPair([NSObject class], "Josh", 0);

        class_addIvar(Josh, "age", sizeof(int), rint(log2(sizeof(int))), @encode(int));

        Ivar ageIvar = class_getInstanceVariable(Josh, "age");
        ptrdiff_t ageIvarOffset = ivar_getOffset(ageIvar);

        IMP ageImp = imp_implementationWithBlock(^int(id self) {
            void *base = (__bridge void *)self;
            return *(int *)((unsigned char *)base + ageIvarOffset);
        });
        class_addMethod(Josh, @selector(age), ageImp, "v@:");

        IMP initImp = imp_implementationWithBlock(^id(id self) {
            struct objc_super superInfo = {
                .receiver = self,
                .super_class = NSObject.self
            };
            id (*msgSendSuper)(struct objc_super *, SEL) = (id (*)(struct objc_super *, SEL))objc_msgSendSuper;
            self = msgSendSuper(&superInfo, @selector(init));
            if (self) {
                void *base = (__bridge void *)self;
                *(int *)((unsigned char *)base + ageIvarOffset) = 10;
            }
            return self;
        });
        class_addMethod(Josh, @selector(init), initImp, "@@:");

        objc_registerClassPair(Josh);
        // Below is the desired result
        id j = [[Josh alloc] init];
        NSLog(@"%d", [j age]); // prints 10
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And here's the output:

```
2018-06-25 15:31:41.837748-0500 madness[35369:5786038] 10
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you very much!

Comment: `void *base = (__bridge void *)self;
*(int *)((unsigned char *)base + ageIvarOffset) = 10;` is the way to avoid messing up the values in the class right? Do you happen to know is there a way to do this thing in Swift too?

Comment: It's possible in Swift too using some combination of `UnsafeMutableRawPointer` and `UnsafeMutablePointer` but I'd have to play around for a while to figure out the exact syntax.

Comment: No, no, you have helped a lot! I truly appreciate that! Thanks for the hint and help!

Comment: This is just crazy, but upvoted for the effort put into the answer.